# how to hide file extension from the middle of the url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with hide URL in `.htaccess`. I want to remove `.php` from the URL.

For Example: convert `www.example.com/destination_info.php/Laos-destination-trip` to `www.example.com/destination_info/Laos-destination-trip`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Please describe what problem you get.

Comment: what if url is:: www.example.com/test.php, should it show www.example.com/test ..
?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: http://www.moccatravels.com/destination_info.php/Laos-destination-trip
I used this code to hide the extension but this is not working ....

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]

Comment: Is there some CMS framework like CI in place here. Also you should edit the question and post your .htaccess code there as it is not possible to understand it from comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example `yoursite.com/wallpaper.php` to `yoursite.com/wallpaper` you have to add the following code inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

A reference to the full article can be found [here](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

To hide .php use following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To hide html

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the rule in the middle of the URL for an API like in my case, then use the first answer from @anubhava. That worked for me.

Also, I'm using IIS so I had to install the Rewrite Module and then Import the rule from the first answer. Second and Third answers will work only for the last part of the URL.